# How to create SSL cetificate from Synology from Letsencrypt?

Tags: tls, ip, letsencrypt

There is option in New Synology to create SSL for local or remote host. But when define a subdomain it's give back can't verify to Host/ connect.

My question is, is that only possible when Synology defines a FFDQ with real ip can have a SSL certificate from letsencrypt?

Comment: Since Synology is not a security product, you're unlikely going to get an answer here. You may want to check on their support forums.

Answer (score 1):

Letsencrypt needs access to the client, Synology in this case, in order to verify the authenticity of your (sub)domain claim. There are other ways of doing this however. As far as I know, Letsencrypt only allows domains, not subdomains.

Comment: To be precise Let'sEncrypt count the number of request against domain.tld entries. You can use whatever fqdn you want in the certificate (and even alternate names) as long as Let'sEncrypt can make a http Get toward the authentification token for each fqdn (obvisouly working DNS is required). You can also make a DNS challenge if you have access to the domain to create the TXT records needed to prove you own the domain (which could be a subdomain also, the txt record is at the same level as the fqdn).